# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table"" (postgres db) in seqauilize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to calculate avarage rating from associated table. I wrote the code as given below. When I execute the code it generates error :

> "error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ratings" "

```
GigWorkers.findAll({
                    limit,
                    offset,
                    where:{},
                    attributes: {
                        include: [ 
                          [sequelize.fn('AVG', sequelize.col('ratings.rating')), 'avgRatings'],
                        ],
                    },
                    include: [
                        GigType, 
                        GigWorkerMeta, 
                        {
                            model: ProfilePhoto,
                            where:{
                                type:"profile"
                            }, 
                            required:false,
                        },
                        {
                            model: Documents,
                            where:{
                                type:"profile"
                            }, 
                            required:false,
                        },
                        {
                            model:Referee,
                            required:false,
                        },
                        {
                            model:Ratings,
                            as:"ratings",
                            attributes: [],
                            required:false,
                        }
                    ],
                    group: ['gig_workers.id'],
                    distinct: true,
                    //required:false,
                });
```

Resulting sql:

```
SELECT "gig_workers".*, "gig_types"."id" AS "gig_types.id", "gig_types"."name" AS "gig_types.name", "gig_types"."qualifications" AS "gig_types.qualifications", "gig_types"."experience" AS "gig_types.experience", "gig_types"."pay_rate" AS "gig_types.pay_rate", "gig_types"."dress_code" AS "gig_types.dress_code", "gig_types"."active" AS 
"gig_types.active", "gig_types"."createdAt" AS "gig_types.createdAt", "gig_types"."updatedAt" AS "gig_types.updatedAt", "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel"."gigWorkerId" AS "gig_types.gig_worker_type_rel.gigWorkerId", "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel"."gigTypeId" AS "gig_types.gig_worker_type_rel.gigTypeId", "gig_worker_metas"."id" AS "gig_worker_metas.id", "gig_worker_metas"."gig_worker_id" AS "gig_worker_metas.gig_worker_id", "gig_worker_metas"."key" AS "gig_worker_metas.key", "gig_worker_metas"."value" AS "gig_worker_metas.value", "gig_worker_metas"."createdAt" AS "gig_worker_metas.createdAt", "gig_worker_metas"."updatedAt" AS "gig_worker_metas.updatedAt", "profile_photos"."id" AS "profile_photos.id", "profile_photos"."user_id" AS "profile_photos.user_id", "profile_photos"."url" AS "profile_photos.url", "profile_photos"."type" AS "profile_photos.type", "profile_photos"."case_id" AS "profile_photos.case_id", "profile_photos"."createdAt" AS "profile_photos.createdAt", "profile_photos"."updatedAt" AS "profile_photos.updatedAt", "documents"."id" AS "documents.id", "documents"."user_id" AS "documents.user_id", "documents"."url" AS "documents.url", "documents"."type" AS "documents.type", "documents"."case_id" AS "documents.case_id", "documents"."createdAt" AS "documents.createdAt", "documents"."updatedAt" AS "documents.updatedAt", "referees"."id" AS "referees.id", "referees"."first_name" AS "referees.first_name", "referees"."last_name" AS "referees.last_name", "referees"."email" AS "referees.email", "referees"."phone" AS "referees.phone", "referees"."role" AS "referees.role", "referees"."job_venue" AS "referees.job_venue", "referees"."gig_worker_id" AS "referees.gig_worker_id", "referees"."assessment_given" 
AS "referees.assessment_given", "referees"."gig_worker_assessment" AS "referees.gig_worker_assessment", "referees"."score" AS "referees.score", "referees"."createdAt" AS "referees.createdAt", "referees"."updatedAt" AS "referees.updatedAt", "ratings"."id" AS "ratings.id", "ratings"."gig_id" AS "ratings.gig_id", "ratings"."business_id" AS "ratings.business_id", "ratings"."gig_worker_id" AS "ratings.gig_worker_id", "ratings"."type" AS "ratings.type", "ratings"."rating" AS "ratings.rating", "ratings"."evaluation" AS "ratings.evaluation", "ratings"."review" AS "ratings.review", "ratings"."assessment_given" AS "ratings.assessment_given", "ratings"."createdAt" AS "ratings.createdAt", "ratings"."updatedAt" AS "ratings.updatedAt" FROM (SELECT "gig_workers"."id", "gig_workers"."user_id", "gig_workers"."first_name", "gig_workers"."last_name", "gig_workers"."address", "gig_workers"."contact_number", "gig_workers"."profile_picture", "gig_workers"."work_rights", "gig_workers"."status", "gig_workers"."verified", "gig_workers"."available_time", "gig_workers"."license", "gig_workers"."venue_experience", "gig_workers"."certification", "gig_workers"."language", "gig_workers"."latitude", "gig_workers"."longitude", "gig_workers"."radius", "gig_workers"."createdAt", "gig_workers"."updatedAt", 
AVG("ratings"."rating") AS "avgRatings" FROM "gig_workers" AS "gig_workers" GROUP BY "gig_workers"."id" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) AS "gig_workers"
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "gig_worker_type_rels" AS "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel" INNER JOIN "gig_types" AS "gig_types" ON "gig_types"."id" = "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel"."gigTypeId") ON "gig_workers"."id" = "gig_types->gig_worker_type_rel"."gigWorkerId" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "gig_worker_metas" AS "gig_worker_metas" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "gig_worker_metas"."gig_worker_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "profile_photos" AS "profile_photos" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "profile_photos"."case_id" AND "profile_photos"."type" = 'profile' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "documents" AS "documents" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "documents"."case_id" AND "documents"."type" = 'profile' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "referees" AS "referees" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "referees"."gig_worker_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "ratings" AS "ratings" ON "gig_workers"."id" = "ratings"."gig_worker_id";
```

Comment: I have given the resulting sql

Comment: The problem is the `AVG("ratings"."rating") AS "avgRatings"` in the subquery that selects only from `gig_workers`. Since I don't know what the query is supposed to do, that is all that I can say.

Comment: thanks for reply. I also got the problem.